# Deep learning(CNN) in physics studies

Tags: experimental-physics

I know that deep learning (especially CNN) is used in many physics studies nowadays.

For example, it is used to distinguish whether the pulse read by the oscilloscope is fast neutron or gamma.
Its performance is quite good.

But at the same time, I've heard that some people are skeptical of using deep learning in physics research.

Deep learning or random forest (machine learning) works well, but it's basically a dark box model. Humans can't understand what criteria produce the corresponding results within it. That's where we don't know the physics. Therefore, sometimes even if deep learning produces very good results, it is not accepted into a good journal unless it is physically interpreted.

I'd like to know more about your opinion on deep learning in physics research.

Thanks.

Comment: *I'd like to know more about your opinion...* opinions aren't something we deal with here

Comment: *I'd like to know more about your opinion on deep learning in physics research.* Opinion-based questions are off-topic. Please edit your question so that it has an objective answer.

Comment: Questions that require opinion are discouraged at this site. Can you modify the question to be more objective? Also more about physics. This is about how to do research more than any physics concept. As is, I am voting to close. It is a good question, but not a good fit for the site.

Comment: Maybe try physicsforums.com.